# importing GoogleCredentials to connect to BigQuery

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-bigquery, google-oauth

I am having troubles connecting to Google's BigQuery while following this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/authorization) in Java.

My problem is that I cannot resolve the method :

```
GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(HttpTransport t, JsonFactory f);
```

Even though I am importing the right package :

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
```

And I added what I think is the right Library :

```
com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.19.0
```

Here is my full code :

```
package com.test.tester;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.BigqueryScopes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;

public class BigQuerytest {

    private static Bigquery createAuthorizedClient() throws IOException {
        Collection<String> bigqueryScopes = BigqueryScopes.all();
        HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(
                transport, jsonFactory);
        if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
            credential = credential.createScoped(bigqueryScopes);
        }
        return new Bigquery.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("BigQuery Samples").build();
    }
}
```

I believe my problem comes from the Google Credentials library which is not the right one but I tried many other and none worked...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your app cradle file

`compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-bigquery:v2-rev245-1.20.0'`